# How can I obtain the timestamp of when an OpenStreetMap element was last modified using OSMnx?

Tags: osmnx

I am using the following code to search for OSM elements within a certain distance of a coordinate:

```
gdf = ox.geometries_from_point( (lat, lon), dist=distance, tags=tags)
```

It works and returns 0, 1 or more elements (nodes, ways and/or relations) and I am able to obtain the info I need.

My question:  How can I find out when the element in question was last modified, i.e. the timestamp of the OSM changeset that it was last included in?  I searched through the documentation but could not find the answer readily.